# Solve the problem with numbers from 1 to 101 written in a random order

Tags: random, ordered-fields

Numbers from 1 to 101 are written in a row in a random order forming a list. Prove that you
 can remove 90 numbers from this list such that remaining numbers will be sorted in the
 ascending or descending order.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: The tags "ordered-fields" and "random" are not really relevant to the question.  You should probably use "combinatorics" "pigeonhole-principle" or "discrete-mathematics" instead.  And your question is a special case of the Erdős–Szekeres theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Szekeres_theorem.